# Cropping a point cloud with PDAL also strips it off

Tags: clip, extents, point-cloud, pdal, cloudcompare

### Description of the problem:

When cropping a `.ply` point cloud using PDAL pipeline:

```
    {
      "pipeline":[
        "input.ply",
        {
          "type":"filters.crop",
          "bounds":"([52435.72, 63951.79], [53477.36, 58371.35])" 
        },
        {
          "type":"writers.ply",
          "filename":"output.ply"
        }
      ]
    }
```

it also "strips" the point cloud.
Here are some screenshots from CloudCompare:

[image: PDAL Cropped cloud view from above (xy plane)]
*Fig. 1 PDAL Cropped cloud view from above (xy plane).*

[image: PDAL Cropped cloud view from front (xz plane)]
*Fig. 2 PDAL Cropped cloud view from front (xz plane).*

[image: Original point cloud view from front (xz plane). Exact same viewing position and orientation as the second image above. The original point cloud is denser and more homogeneous.]
*Fig. 3 Original point cloud view from front (xz plane). Exact same viewing position and orientation as the second image above. The original point cloud is denser and more homogeneous.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

When not specified, it's the ASCII format that is used by the PLY writer. This impacts the precision of the points.

Header of the original CloudCompare point cloud:

```
$ head -n16 input.ply
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
comment Created by CloudCompare v2.10-alpha
comment Created 03.08.18 14:45
obj_info Generated by CloudCompare!
element vertex 8848475
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property float nx
property float ny
property float nz
end_header
```

Header of the PDAL clipped cloud:

```
$ head -n14 output.ply
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment Generated by PDAL
element vertex 2850721
property float64 x
property float64 y
property float64 z
property uint8 red
property uint8 green
property uint8 blue
property float32 normalx
property float32 normaly
property float32 normalz
end_header
```

### Solution:

Writing a binary file by adding `"storage_mode":"little endian",` in the pipeline:

```
{
  "pipeline":[
    "input.ply",
    {
      "type":"filters.crop",
      "bounds":"([52435.72, 63951.79], [53477.36, 58371.35])" 
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.ply",
      "storage_mode":"little endian",
      "filename":"output.ply"
    }
  ]
}
```

solves the issue.

### Remark:

Please also notice that normals' names from a PDAL cloud are not automatically recognized as such by CloudCompare (they are called `normalx`, `normaly` and `normalz` and CC is waiting for `Nx`, `Ny` and `Nz`); therefore one has to select them manually from the ComboBox when importing the clipped cloud in CC.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, but with a .las file.

The issue was the `scale_x, scale_y, scale_z` parameters. By default in PDAL, they are set to 0.01, which truncated my point cloud.